# SharePoint CSWP - Relative Paths for images

Tags: sharepoint-server, cswp

Morning folks,

I recently extended a Web Application in our SharePoint farm to get ready for AD FS as another Authentication Provider. The original WA comes with the URL https://portal-int.sharepoint.com, the extended is called via https://portal.sharepoint.com.

My problem now is, that all CSWP try to render images with the portal-int URL, no matter if I'm looking from "outside" (via portal.sharepoint.com) or from "inside" (via portal-int.sharepoint.com). CQWP work like a charm but are unfortunately not usable in this scenario.
It's not the query itself that makes trouble but the rendering.

How to solve that? I didn't find any good query for google, etc. which would lead me into the wanted direction. Maybe some of you have an idea?!